# Why does Android Studio highlight "Theme" red in styles.xml?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

Red highlight means **Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme'**

[image]

**Here are some configurations :**

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

...

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

.

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
}
```

...

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.mobile.slider'
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
```

.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

---

It is working nice with my phone Nexus 4 whose android version is
4.4.4. Even though, There is no build problem, NoTitleWindow Mode doesn't work for
another phone which has 2.3.3 android version.

Comment: Is appcompat-v7:19.0.0 in your external libraries folder? And is the dependency set in rightclick on project - open module settings - your module name - dependencies?

Comment: I had added appcompatv7 project as a module but I have forgotten to show it to my application module. Just I have realized and fixed. Now it doesn't alert me anymore. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @codelovesme what do you mean by "show it to my application module" ? Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to attach appcompactv7 to the application module. But I am not sure where in the panel to do that, right now I am not developing Android right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

1. Go to your project directory (or to Project View)
2. Go into the `.idea` directory
3. Remove `caches` and `libraries` directories
4. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Should be OK now.

Answer (score 2):

I had added appcompatv7 project as a module but I have forgotten to show it to my application module. Just I have realized and fixed. Now it doesn't alert me anymore. Thanks for your reply, tritop.

Comment: "project module"

Answer (score 0):

It's very weird but I had the dependency in my .gradle.

To solve the issue I deleted it(//commented), sync, get all error because of it, put the dependency again, sync again. Then the problem was gone!

Answer (score 0):

## Only this worked for me!

- Close project (File> Close Project)
- Import / Re-Open project again (**NOT from Recent**)

Error should be resolved now.

If that did not resolve, then try below

- Open build.gradle, remove `appcompact-v7` dependency line and sync.
- Again add `appcompact-v7` dependency and sync.

Issue must be resolved!

Answer (score 0):

**Just delete the dependencies below and sync. Paste them again and sync.**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```