# Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' in styles.xml

Tags: android, gradle, themes, android-appcompat

Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar is not compiling in styles.xml. I have added `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'` in app module's 
`build.gradle`. [image: Theme Error]

I have searched for solution in google. A lot of them are about changing the classpath in Project's `build.gradle`.Still its showing the same error.

```
build.gradle

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    //    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode = 146
        versionName = "0.6.65"
    }
```

Comment: try cleaning the project and rebuild

Comment: Did that as well.Still persists.

Comment: post your gradle as well

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: Hi, check my question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40782046/5241603

Comment: That's becouse of "Build cache" feature. see here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765120/1148784

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your build.gradle version is simply the wrong one.

Follow these instructions to fix that:

- In Android studio, go to the Gradle scripts section in the left panel.
- Find the file:  `build.gradle(Project:{your_project_name})`
- In that file look at the line `com.android.tools.build:gradle`
- Check that the version match with your android studio version (for instance 2.3.3). This implies that `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` and And an Android studio distribution with 2.3.3 as version.
- Validate the versions are the same. If it's not the case, make sure they match.
- Rebuild the project and everything is fine!

Comment: solved my issue too, after making sure the gradle plugin version matches the android studio version (it didn't match at first) i got more specific errors that indicated exactly what was wrong.                                    thanks!

Comment: Didn't understand the science, but anyway it worked! +1

Comment: This could be the best solution +1

Answer (score 21):

Go to File > Close the Project. Then import it back and restart Android Studio.

Comment: none of the above didn't work for me. this worked :)

Comment: Woked in my case too!

Comment: A-mazing. Worked for me. Android Studio & Gradle plugin = 3.1.2. Gradle 4.4

Comment: I don't know how, but it fix my problem

Answer (score 10):

```
<style name="Theme.Base.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

In case when clean/rebuild not work, just delete .gradle directory in your project root. And sync project with gradle again.

This issue is caused when you mix cache of your support libraries.

Answer (score 9):

I have noticed that all themes available with the prefix `@android:style/` can be used. So, I have solved this issue by replacing

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

with

`@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: That wont work if your activity is extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: That is replacing one theme (shipped with your app) with another (shipped with your OS), this is not a fix

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, what fixed it for me was retrograding gradle plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
```

Followed by a project sync with gradle files to clear the problem.

Comment: For some reason, switching to 2.2.3 from 2.3.3 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try one of the following solutions:

1. delete `.gradle` folder under the project
2. if the project is imported from Eclipse, or it is an old project

   1. upgrade `minSdkVersion` in `app/build.gradle`, eg. 14 or 16, which is greater than 8 !
   2. remove the `minSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` configuration in `AndroidManifest.xml` !
3. import `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` library in `app/build.gradle`
4. upgrade your Android Studio to the latest version
5. if it still doesn't work, maybe you can:

   1. restart Android Studio
   2. delete the project in Android Studio and reimport it.

Comment: Thanks. Deleting `.gradle` helped to compile a project. For me another solution helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094111/2914140.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle file , set compileSdkVersion  to 25 .
Following gradle is working for me with appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 26
        versionName "3.16"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' . It's already above 23.

Comment: I checked with buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' , in the Android Studio project , it working , plz check .

Comment: I'm using  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'. and  compileSdkVersion 25. What am i missing?

Comment: You are using  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' but I am suggesting you buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' .

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

try this

Comment: *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870303/ide-cannot-resolve-style-theme-appcompat-when-using-v7-compatibility-support*  follow it may help in more detail

Comment: This worked. But i think its more of a hack than solution. anyway thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17885102/6546446

Comment: Why should he use an old version of appcompat? No, it can't be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change in style.xml file as `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>`

Answer (score 0):

I did everything as has been suggested in the accepted answer and it didn't help. Then I did everything as has been suggested in this answer: [Android studio cannot find Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509096/android-studio-cannot-find-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar) (enabled all components in Repository) and it didn't help either.

The issue has been only resolved after clicking on "Synchronized" in File menu. I'm running Android 3.0.1 on Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Android 3.0.1, tried doing "Synchronize", Resysnching gradle etc but nothing helped, I then found that adding

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'` line fixed the issue

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1. Close android studio project.
2. Remove project from recent.
3. Go to project directory and delete ".gradle" directory.
4. Open project from option "Open an existing Android Studio Project".

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and it is because in my new style and it is because when I declare a new style I put "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" in the name instead of parent.
I change from :

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

to

```
<style name="ThisTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions, including deleting of `.gradle` folder (yes, it works, a project becomes compilable), but red themes didn't disappear.

This [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220842/2914140) helped:

- Go into the `.idea` directory
- Remove `caches` and `libraries` directories
- File -> Invalidate Caches -> Restart

Answer (score 0):

> ### This solution worked for me

- Close project (File> Close Project)
- Import / Re-Open project again (**NOT from Recent**)

**Error should be resolved now.**

If that fails, try below-

- Open build.gradle, remove `appcompact-v7` dependency and sync project.
- Add `appcompact-v7` dependency and sync.

Issue solved!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to wrong gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties.

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-**5.0**-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

My theme parent was `android:Theme.Light` and I wanted to change it to the AppCompat version. I mistakenly changed it to `android:Theme.AppCompat.Light`, but instead I needed to change it to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do **Refactor > Migrate to AppCompat...**.
It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

The fix for me was to delete the .gradle folder in my project root, then click file and click "Synchronize". everything worked after that.

Comment: You should be clear what "tried the above" means. You can link directly to an answer that you found did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove and add this below lines again in **build.gradle** i.e. **app.gradle**  and sync it:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

as per your android version.........

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please explain why your solution solves the problem. Also the support libraries posted are for level 26, but the user is compiling against 25. But there is no real warning of the consequences.

Comment: Should we downgrade support libraries?

Comment: @CoolMind:No need to do that, based on your current API use the supporting libraries

Comment: @Elletlar: Maybe your target API is 26, nut the main thing is it solved your problem.... :)