# Cannot resolve symbol 'AppTheme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'

Tags: android, android-layout, styles

[I can't understand what is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztfol.png)

```html
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Neither we . Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177304/cannot-resolve-symbol-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar-in-styles-xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also check your `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` dependency

Comment: i am already add this dependency
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil Build > Clean Project

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil pay attention to this answer, she changed the parent from "AppTheme" to "Theme" which is the correct parent for your problem.