# in android studio 3.1.4 Can not use "?attr/actionBarSize"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

after update **android studio** to `version 3.1.4` Can not use `?attr/actionBarSize` in *xml*.

Comment: any logcat or error messages.

Comment: @navylover Cannot resolve symbol '?attr/actionBarSize' less...
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

**XML**

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?attr/actionBarSize` still, the issue is that Android Studio is showing error on `?attr/actionBarSize`. Almost every android developer has faced this issue in AS 3+.

**Solution**

- Close project
- Open project again (not from recent)

**Resolved! :)**

By the way, all below works still

```
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Related question :

[Why does Android Studio highlight "Theme" red in styles.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25265328/6891563)

[Cannot resolve symbol Theme, ThemeOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47726293/6891563)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

**instead of**

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```